# Matlab, how to iterate over a multi dimentional array

Tags: matlab

I am trying this code

```
arr = [[400, 200], [100, 50]]

for a = arr

    a(2) % Should display the 2nd element of the sub-array   

end
```

but I get:

```
Index exceeds the number of array elements (1)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I have an idea of why the error appears, but I have no idea what you want to do. to display `a(2)` you don't need a loop. Just `a(:,2)`. but also, where did you read how to write a MATLAB for loop? that is not correct.

Comment: the number of sub arrays is not fixed in my code, that's why i iterate over the total array

Comment: You can rewrite your loop as `for i = 1:length(arr)` and then your `a = arr(i)`. As you can see, `a` is only one element of `arr`, so its size is 1x1.

Comment: @mricdev yes, my proposed solution works for any numer of rows.

Comment: but I want to loop of each subarray.... you don't see the point ?

Comment: so show me how to display [400, 200] and then this [100, 50] in the loop ?

Comment: I dont want a to be one element I want a to be [400, 200] then [100, 50]

Comment: I think you're confusing Matlab's language with some other (Python I guess?). `[[400, 200], [100, 50]]` just horizontally concatenates the two subarrays and returns a single array `[400, 200, 100, 50]`. You'd better use cells `arr = {[400, 200], [100, 50]}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to define `arr` differently, i.e.:

```
arr = [400 200; 100 50];
```